# OpenCV: At what index do Mat objects start?

Tags: opencv, matrix, indexing

I understand that the `Mat` in OpenCV follows the mathematical convention of the order of the row and the col parameter, which is row first and col second. But how about the start index? Is it 0 like in informatics or 1 like the maths?

Moreover, is the convention for the start index consistent over all the methods, most prominently `at<_Tp>()`, `rowRange()`, and `colRange()`?

Just a note for myself:

```
Mat m = ...;
Vec4b e = m.at<Vec4b>(        i, j ); // equivalent to next line (note swapped i and j)
Vec4b e = m.at<Vec4b>(Point2i(j, i));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its starts at 0. Same for rowRange, colRange. Drawing functions such as `cv::rectangle` however, are in image coordinates: 0,0 is the top left, x along image width (matrix columns), y along image height (matrix rows)

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clearer for me. For the top left corner: Isn't (0, 0) also the top left for at<_Tp>() and the others mentioned?

Comment: yes, at<>(0,0) is at the 0th row, 0th column of the matrix which is the top left